# 'Back stack's basic

Tags: android, back-stack

I read the developers guide on android.com about [Task and back stacks](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html) where it says:

> Suppose, for example, that the current task (Task A) has three
>   activities in its stack—two under the current activity. The user
>   presses the HOME key, then starts a new application from the
>   application launcher. When the Home screen appears, Task A goes into
>   the background. When the new application starts, the system starts a
>   task for that application (Task B) with its own stack of activities.
>   After interacting with that application, the user returns Home again
>   and selects the application that originally started Task A. Now, Task
>   A comes to the foreground—all three activities in its stack are intact
>   and the activity at the top of the stack resumes.

It seems like every Task creates it own stack (back stack). Is my assumption is real or there's only one stack, usually a compiler has, like C?

Answer (score 1):

The back stack can cross Task boundaries. When the `launchmode` for an activity is set to `singleTask`, the activity will be created in a new task.

Suppose activity `B` has `launchmode=singleTask` in the XML file. When activity `A` launches activity `B`, the latter will be in its own task. However, pressing the `back` key will bring the user back to activity `A`. So `A` and `B` are in the same back stack, but are in different tasks.

See the discussion of `launchmode` in the page  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html.

---

disclaimer: I have not verified if the documentation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that what they say is true!  Every Task creates it own stack (back stack).